# Receiving same message multiple times through Subscription IBM MQ

Tags: java, ibm-mq, publish-subscribe

Only in one of the subscription message listener is getting same message multiple times. I am using weblogic server and using Ejb. 
I am using a durable subscription. I have tried SHARED and CLONED both but separately and still the issue is same

```
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionDurability", propertyValue = "Durable"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionName", propertyValue = ""),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "sharedSubscription", propertyValue = "TRUE")
   })
```

CLONED

```
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionDurability", propertyValue = "Durable"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionName", propertyValue = ""),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "cloneSupport", propertyValue = "ENABLED"),
```

So i am using Abstarct Class which implemant message listener

```
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
    LOGGER.info("Receive Host message: {}", message);
```

I parse the message and then in some different method I sendACK

```
protected void createAndSendAckMessage(String msgToSend, Message request) throws JMSException {
    Connection connection = null;
    Session session = null;
    MessageProducer producer = null;

    try {
        connection = getConnectionFactory().createConnection();
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

In a different MDB which a subscriber I extend that abstract class and define all the @ActivationConfigProperty

I am creating a .binding file to specify port, Host, qmanager and topics information

Comment: @JoshMc Its ibm MQ 8. It is owned by the customer. Customer and we both using same version mq libraries.

Comment: @JoshMc  its 8.0.0.4

Comment: @JoshMc any random string...like testcleint

Comment: @JoshMc I am the only subscriber to the message...

Comment: If you have only a single subscriber application then why are you bothering with cloned and shared subscriptions?  The purpose of those is if you want to have multiple subscriber applications "share" a single subscription meaning that instead of all of them getting a copy of all published messages, only one of them would get a copy of any message published.

Comment: @JoshMc it’s just I am getting duplicate messages continuously and I don’t know how to stop it. I read that clones and shared subscription might help. Is there any way to stop that....because publisher is only sending the message once

Comment: With a durable subscription if you are NOT committing the message they will still be on the queue.  Is the program getting an error and backing it out and then getting it a 2nd, 3rd, etc time?

Comment: I am not sure of that part since customer owns the mq and according to them message never gets removed and I am doing sesssion.autoacknowledge. I just can’t figure out what am I doing wrong. Yes the message is getting continuously

Comment: The your question is describing the wrong problem.  You are not getting duplicate messages, you are getting the same message multiple times.  I think you need to edit your question, start over a bit and describe in detail what you are doing.  What application server is this running in (WAS, Weblogic, WildFly, etc), are you use Spring or Camel, provide the full details of your MDB configuration, with obfuscated values where needed.

Comment: I have edited a little but surely edit more in the morning with more code...thanks for the help till now:)

Comment: Does the createAndSendAckMessage get called and send the ack message each time you reread the published message?  I also see from what you posed that createAndSendAckMessage has `Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE`, what does your MDB have?

Comment: Yes however from the second message, i send an error message back stating duplicate messageID.  My MDB has all the properties which i stated in the questition like                       
   @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic"),
                                                                                                                                                Its extending the AbstarctMDB and calling the HostMessageProcessor.

Comment: I don't see the session type listed in your MDB?

Comment: protected void createAndSendAckMessage(String msgToSend, Message request) throws JMSException {
        Connection connection = null;
        Session session = null;
        MessageProducer producer = null;

        try {
            connection = getConnectionFactory().createConnection();
            session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            TextMessage ackMessage = session.createTextMessage(msgToSend);


            if (request.getJMSReplyTo() != null) {
                producer = session.createProducer(request.getJMSReplyTo());

Comment: So i just do Session session = null; in createAndSendAckMessage method and then session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

Comment: Is the "createAndSendAckMessage" part of your MDB?  I thought the MDB is listening to the published messages and separately you are sending back a Ack message outside of the MDB?   In any case the  Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE in the context presented is related to the sending of the Ack message, what is the Session set to in the MDB in relation to the receiving of the published messages?  Can you please edit your question and add the additional code, as you can see above comments are not formatted so it is just a jumble.